# The use of Mage_Core_Block_Flush block

Tags: blocks, magento-1

I see that in every version of magento 1 there is this block `Mage_Core_Block_Flush`. I didn't find any usage of it any layout files. What's the purpose of this block? There is a comment at the top of the class

> Immediate flush block. To be used only as root

but that's not totally clear to me.
A use case when this might be needed should suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not used by the core (afaik). It turns off output buffering, so the rendered output would be sent immediately. The only block where it would kind of work would be the root block, otherwise the nested `core/flush` block and all following blocks would be rendered before the containing outer blocks.

I can't think of a sensible use case. Since the front controller is responsible for sending the output to the client, the `core/flush` block breaks his process. In the worst case it could lead to PHP Headers already sent notices.

I don't know, but my guess is it is a relict from the pre-release days of Magento, where the whole rendering system wasn't finalized yet. Probably seemed like a good idea at the time.
Maybe someone who was with the core team at the time can enlighten us about the history.

Credit to [VinaiKopp](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/766/vinai)

This block is removed from magento [Magento 2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35#issuecomment-7265641)

Comment: Seams reasonable. Thanks. I also see that this block is not ported to Magento 2. So it's probably just an unfinished feature.

Comment: fentastic observation Keyur, +1 for that. Oh it seems that,you just copied Vinai's answer. So put the credit to Vinai in your answer :-)

Comment: I have updated my answer with magento 2 link @Marius

Comment: @KeyurShah. I just found the link for Magento 2. That's why I said it was removed. Thanks. Unfortunately I cannot upvote the answer twice :).

Comment: one upvote for this case....

Comment: Yeah i have updated my answer :-) @RajeevKTomy

Comment: @KeyurShah Seen it and now your answer completes. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

It could be used as root block for an iframe that shows a long running process with real time output. The same technique is used for the console in the Magento Connect manager.